# Install node red nodes/packages by copying them?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node-red

Hey I got a server with a normal node red installation it had no flows and I imported some flows with he import function. Now a node is missing and my question is can I install this node without internet connection by just copying it from another server? Like copying the folder of the node in the mode_modules folder or just add the name in the package.json file? Or maybe both? And then use npm install to install it?

It's a customer system so I couldnt try anything yet cause I don't want to break anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible.
Here is what you can do:

- Locate the missing node's module folder within the node_modules directory on the server where the node is installed.
- Copy the entire folder for the missing node.
- If you copied the entire module folder, you might not need to manually edit package.json. However, it's a good idea to check if the node is listed in the dependencies section of the package.json file. If not, add it.
- If the node has specific configuration files or settings, make sure to copy those as well.
- Before making changes on the customer's system, I suggest you set up a test environment (if possible) to ensure that the copied node works correctly with all its dependencies.
  Once you've copied the necessary files, you can try running npm install in the Node installation directory. This should install the missing node and its dependencies.

Keep in mind that this approach may not work for all nodes, especially if the node relies on external resources that are not included in the copied files. Additionally, be cautious and test thoroughly in a safe environment before applying changes to a customer's system.

If you encounter any issues or if the node has complex dependencies, it might be worth considering an alternative approach, such as creating a package with all the required files and dependencies and then installing it on the customer's system.

Comment: Modern versions of `npm` deduplicate a nodes dependencies, so you can't just copy a single node's directory out of the `node_modules` directory as it will not contain all the dependencies. The ONLY way to make this work is to take the whole `node_modules` directory from the Node-RED userDir.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible it requires that you copy from a machine the same OS (and version) and architecture and exactly the same version of NodeJS.

A MUCH better solution to this problem is to install docker on the target machine and create a Docker container by extending the Node-RED container to include the flow and all it's dependant nodes.

Docker containers can be exported as tar files which can then be copied to the offline machine and imported. The docker container will then contain all the required nodes and all the required dependencies as a single package that is MUCH easier to manage.